# Dart formatting issue [VSCODE]

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, formatting

Could anyone explain to me why dart formats the code in a way it does it? 
I have the dart plugin installed and have used the 'Dart: Use recommended settings'.

```
Future<void> addProduct(Product product) {
    return http
        .post(
      '$url.json',
      body: json.encode(
        {
          'title': product.title,
          'description': product.description,
          'imageUrl': product.imageUrl,
          'price': product.price,
          'isFavorite': product.isFavorite,
        },
      ),
    )
        .then((response) {
      var id = json.decode(response.body)['name'];
      var newProduct = Product(
        description: product.description,
        title: product.title,
        price: product.price,
        imageUrl: product.imageUrl,
        id: id,
      );
      _items.add(newProduct);
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((err) {});
  }
```

Comment: most likely the plugin uses [dartfmt](https://dart.dev/tools/dartfmt) (i dont think the plugin formats your code internally)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the Dart extension just delegates formatting to [dartfmt](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-format) so the formatting is based on its conventions, including 2-spaces for indenting and 4-space indenting for line continuations.

dartfmt is an opinionated formatter so there's not much that can be controlled, though trailing commas will affect how it formats some code:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting

[image]
<sub>(source: [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/assets/tools/android-studio/trailing-comma-with-1d6907af995766eb14afba227e3c54d015fc02a2c15bc1779cae60696660c72e.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/assets/tools/android-studio/trailing-comma-without-d0af20c73d2eb7d0a74664cc0acae7e30d01007d9fa172fceda4cd531b909a19.png))</sub>

Comment: Yes, the UI formatting works good. But this future, the way the then block is aligned feels wrong to me. Will it get formatted in a same way for everyone or there is something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Also, the fact that 'var id' is not indented relative to the '.then' also feels wrong.

Comment: If you put a trailing comma in `}).catchError` it'll partially fix that, but probably not to your liking. I would recommend extracting the functions into local variables to improve that. FWIW, I'm not the biggest fan of the formatting either, I do wish it was less opionated - but I'll take what's there over no automatic formatting :-)

Comment: The trailing comma did partially fixed the issue, thanks!